# Sending the results of a delete statement into an emailed report. (Data purge report)

Tags: sql, sql-server, insert

I would like to send an emailed report that has the table name and number of records deleted during a  scheduled delete execution in SQL Server 2016. Here is an example of my query below.

```
DELETE FROM dbo.f03b11z1
WHERE vjupmj<CONCAT(DATEDIFF(year,'1900-1-1',(GETDATE()-220)) /100,DATEDIFF(year,'1900-1-1',(GETDATE()-220)) % 100, DATEPART(DAYOFYEAR,(GETDATE()-220)) )
  AND vjedsp = '1'

SELECT @@ROWCOUNT AS 'Record_Count'
```

I'm trying to add both the table name and the number of records deleted in the emailed report but with the query below I'm not able to achieve what is needed.

```
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
          @profile_name = 'SQL DBA',  
          @recipients = 'myemail.com',  
          @body = 'Insert text here',
          @body_format = TEXT,
          @query = 'EXECUTE spname',
          @execute_query_database = 'QA',
          @subject = 'Deleted record count',
          @query_result_header = 1,
          @query_result_width = 256,
          @query_result_separator = ',',
          @query_result_no_padding = 1;
```

I have tried running the following with no luck. I'm assuming that I need to add an `AS Tablename` clause to my query.

```
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
    @profile_name = 'SQL DBA',  
    @recipients = 'myemail.com',  
    @body = 'Insert text here',
    @body_format = text,
    @query = 'EXECUTE sp',
    @execute_query_database = 'QA',
    @subject = 'Data purge record count',
    @attach_query_result_as_file = 1,
    @query_attachment_filename = 'Monthly_Purge.csv',
    @query_result_header = 1,
    @query_result_width = 256,
    @query_result_separator = ',',
    @exclude_query_output = 1,
    @append_query_error = 1,
    @query_no_truncate = 0,
    @query_result_no_padding = 1;
```

Any ideas?

Edit: My goal was for the output to look like the following.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DTEUf.png)

Adding the following code gets me the image above but when I email it via a spreadsheet it comes out in a different format as seen below.

SELECT 'dbo.f03b11z1' as TableName, @@ROWCOUNT AS 'Record_Count'

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SxqYT.png)

Comment: Like `SELECT 'dbo.f03b11z1' as TableName, @@ROWCOUNT AS 'Record_Count'`

Comment: This `vjupmj<CONCAT` doesn't appear valid.

Comment: Why would you do all that to yourself? [Which one is easier to read](https://dbfiddle.uk/2ZiCQxLj)? Or [in this example](https://dbfiddle.uk/X4RnrsUb)?

Comment: If the stored procedure is hard-coded to select from `dbo.f03b11z1` then why can't you just hard-code it in the `SELECT`, too, as Dale pointed out?

Comment: What in heavens does "no luck" mean? Are you getting an error message? Are you getting an email with no email attachment? Is the email queueing successfully by then there are error message(s) in `select * from msdb.dbo.sysmail_mailitems;` and/or `select * from msdb.dbo.sysmail_log;`?

Comment: Have you captured and checked the return status value from `msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail` yet? It should be `0` for success or `1` if some kind of failure was detected.

Comment: Have you tried database-qualifying the stored procedure name in the execute statement - especially if it's not in the database specified by `@execute_query_database = 'QA'`?

Comment: Does the stored procedure start with `SET NOCOUNT ON;`? Possibly the sqlcmd client behind sp_send_dbmail is getting confused by the record count from the `DELETE` statement and not even noticing the subsequent record set output by the `SELECT` statment.

Comment: After looking at @AaronBertrand 's "easier to read" version of your date calculation, I realized that you likely have a side issue with date code calculated wrong. Because you are using `CONCAT()` on integer values, you will not get the expected filler zeros, so an expected `'102003'` may come back as `'123'`. See [this db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/XkF9pZiG) for a demo and a fix using `FORMAT()` to add the zero padding. It also appears unnecessary to separately format the year as two parts.

Comment: @TN why “easier to read” in quotes? Even breaking the concat expression from one line to multiple is certainly easier to read on its own. Also, maybe they do store `123` for the date in your fiddle (you came up with the expected result for that date, not the OP). I mean, we are both guessing, but must be a reason (and maybe a very wrong one) they use concat at all.

Comment: @AaronBertrand  - I meant the quotes as true quotes around the descriptive phrase you used in your comment (as opposed to sarcastic "air quotes"). I agree with the concept of breaking out sub-expressions from complex expressions - especially when repeated. The *easier to read* code actually helped me spot the ... Issue. (And maybe I should have used the word "possibly" instead of "likely"). Lastly the "you" was intended to reference the OP - possibly having a side issue that warrants a look. Sorry if it read differently than intended.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning what I meant was that I didn't have any luck getting my output in the correct format. I'm doing a monthly data purge and I need to email a report that has the table name and the number of records that were deleted.

Comment: @TN I don't have any issues with the delete itself, that code is doing a Julian date conversion. My issue is with the format of the emailed results format.

Comment: (Reposted with correction to century prefix) @MichaelDaniels - Just be advised that starting in mid-August, your calculated julian date strings will be transition to funky values `('122364'` -> `'122365'` -> `'1231'` -> `'1232'` -> `'1233'` -> `'1234'`), so that by August 12, the string comparison `vjupmj < '1234'` may select and delete all of your `f03b11z1` data up to and including the present day (and even any prefilled future 2023 values). In other words, all `vjupmj` values `'123001'` through `'123224'` may compare as less than `'1234'` and those records will be deleted.

Comment: However if `vjupmj` is stored as an integer, the results may be less drastic. The comparison `vjupmj < '1234'` may be coerced to an integer compare `vjupmj < 1234`. This would have an opposite effect. Instead of deleting data prematurely, no data will be selected or deleted over a 99 day period. Then eventually in mid-November, 100 days worth of data (Julian date values `123001` - `123100`) may be selected and deleted all at once. (If this behavior occurred last year, perhaps that is why someone has tasked you with generating this email.)

Comment: Regarding your original question: Is your issue with the fact that the result is displaying a "QADTA." prefix instead of "dto." or with the presence if the header, footer, and associated underscore/dash lines? If the latter, what precisely is in the .csv file attachment? Same the attachment a as .csv and open with NotePad. Paste the actual content (not a screen grab) back to your question. There may be solutions where you turn off automatic headers and manually format the message (perhaps even as HTML) in the query result.

Comment: @TN that delete statement actually works correctly converting the julian date. It's already in production and it hasn't deleted any other data besides the previous 180 days or whatever it's set to. I should have worded my problem better. I'm just trying to get the emailed output formated correctly.